# Sinch issue java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, android-library, sinch, android-sinch-api

I getting Bellow Errors in Sinch.
its issue in some Device.

```
Process: com.reach.communications, PID: 14029
                                                                          java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.reach.communications-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.reach.communications-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libsinch-android-rtc.so"
                                                                              at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
                                                                              at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
                                                                              at com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.client.DefaultSinchClient.<clinit>(DefaultSinchClient.java:76)
                                                                              at com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.client.InternalSinchClientFactory.createSinchClient(InternalSinchClientFactory.java:19)
                                                                              at com.sinch.android.rtc.DefaultSinchClientBuilder.build(DefaultSinchClientBuilder.java:95)
                                                                              at com.reach.communications.ui.sinch.SinchService.start(SinchService.java:146)
                                                                              at com.reach.communications.ui.sinch.SinchService.access$200(SinchService.java:19)
                                                                              at com.reach.communications.ui.sinch.SinchService$SinchServiceInterface.startClient(SinchService.java:50)
                                                                              at com.reach.communications.ui.Fragment3.setView(Fragment3.java:91)
                                                                              at com.reach.communications.ui.Fragment3.onCreateView(Fragment3.java:78)
                                                                              at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
                                                                              at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:895)
                                                                              at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1068)
                                                                              at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:840)
                                                                              at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1455)
                                                                              at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:447)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5273)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

please help me how to solve it. i am using android studio.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**build.gradle**

```
android
        {
            compileSdkVersion 23
            buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

 defaultConfig
                    {
                       ...
                       //important code, write in target API 22  
                        minSdkVersion 15
                        targetSdkVersion 22
                        ...
                    }//end defaultConfig

 sourceSets
                    {
                        main
                                {

                                     ...
                                    jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
                                    assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets/']
                                    aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/aidl/']
                                    ...

                                }

                        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
                        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

                        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
                        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
                        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
                        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
                        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
                        // by a similar customization.
                        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
                        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
                    }//end sourceSets


                   ...
                   ...
                 }//end android
```

**Another important thing to do**

You need to create a new folder in `src/main/jniLibs` and add there your *.SO libraries.

[image]

Comment: I have Already jniLibs folder and there have four other folder 1) armeabi
2) armeabi-v7a
3) mips
4) x86 

and 1),2),4) folder have already "libsinch-android-rtc.so" but all size are diffrent help me for next step

Answer (score 0):

Add your `libsinch-android-rtc.so` lib64 version into `/libs`.

Comment: somewhere you get `libsinch-android-rtc.so`. `arm64` or `lib64` is for x64 platform abi.